# How to trim a string in shell script with a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, shell

How's everyone doing?

So, if I run `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname`, it gives the full title of the current window, for example:

`fish home/kibe/Documents — Konsole`

`Blablablabla - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome`

The thing is, I only want the application name (`Konsole` and `Google Chrome`).

I can easily do it in Python, as such:

```py
def getAppTitle (fullStr):
    lastDashIndex = None
    for i in range(len(fullStr)):
        if fullStr[i] == '-' or fullStr[i] == '—':
            lastDashIndex = i
    return fullStr[lastDashIndex+2:] if lastDashIndex else fullStr

print(getAppTitle('blablabla - blablabla - ApplicationName'))
# returns ApplicationName
```

I have been trying to do the same in shell script but I can't do it for the life of me. Also, for some reasons, some applications use "-" (normal dash) and others "—" (em dash).

How can I do that in shell?

Comment: Do you need to trim the space in front the ' Konsole'?

Comment: @thanasisp i thought i did but it seems to work fantastically well; man, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this 'em dash' or dash as the field separator and print the last field:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | awk -F"—|-" '{print $NF}'
```

I am not sure where this 'em dash' comes from, I had to copy paste it for the above command.

---

Maybe better, use two characters as the FS, any dash and a space, to get the same as your script, with the space trimmed.

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | awk -F"— |- " '{print $NF}'
```